# has-danger no longer working on Bootstrap v4 beta?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

According to the [Bootstrap migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#forms):

> Renamed .has-error to .has-danger.

However, that doesn't seem to work. Border and text has not been coloured.

For example:

```
<div class="form-group has-danger">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputDanger1">
    <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/uLa0spfm/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Being that Bootstrap 4 is still in Beta, much of the migration documentation is [not in sync](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23842) with actual releases. [Validation has changed in beta](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation), and `has-danger` no longer exists.

Also see: [Can't make the validation work in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938703/cant-make-the-validation-work-in-bootstrap-4/45938912#45938912)

Answer (score 24):

Managed to get it to work. @ZimSystem is correct about this.

`.has-danger` exist in Alpha version but it was removed in Bootstrap v4 Beta. You will need to use `is-invalid` selector in the input and also include `class="invalid-feedback"` for error message.

Here is example:

```
<div class="form-group has-danger">
    <label class="form-control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can remove the `has-danger` class from `form-group`. it's useless

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the **beta** version doesn't have the `.has-*` classes.
As a work around, use the alpha-6 version

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Updated fiddle with new CDN.

https://jsfiddle.net/uLa0spfm/1/

Comment: If you're going to downvote a 'work around' - at least explain why.