# How implement validation in bootstrap 4 css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I saw this example in the bootstrap 4 documentation:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group has-warning">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputWarning1">Input with warning</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-warning" id="inputWarning1">
   <div class="form-control-feedback">Shucks, check the formatting of that and try again.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-danger">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputDanger1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

However, the edits are not colored

The documentation says that I have to load the CSS, but in CSS the class has-danger is missing

https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Instead in the CSS of bootstrap 3, the class exists

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

In fact if I use the css of bootstrap 3, the edits are colored

How can I use class has-danger in bootstrap 4?
I need to use css no Sass

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179078/has-danger-no-longer-working-on-bootstrap-v4-beta?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Hope this can be of some help.

Comment: would have been faster to type bootstrap4 has-danger into a search engine than this whole question

Answer (score 0):

The Class has-danger is no longer used in bootstrap4 (deprecated) 
use is-invalid selector in the input and also include class="invalid-feedback" in your code

```
<div class="invalid-feedback">
```

Comment: where can I find an example in the documentation?

Comment: @Janka Alpha version is almost ancient. Check the current docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#supported-elements